# WinDbg psscor4 commands !ASPXPages / !DumpHttpContext missing most ThreadId and showing XXX

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, windbg

I'm analyzing a dump file taken with procdump -ma w3wp on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine running .NET 4.

```
0:000> !ASPXPages
Going to dump the HttpContexts found in the heap.
Loading the heap objects into our cache.
HttpContext    Timeout  Completed     Running  ThreadId ReturnCode   Verb RequestPath+QueryString
0x0353f65c      110 Sec        no      1429 Sec     XXX        200   GET /Nav/ResTry.aspx qs1
0x03545a18      110 Sec       yes                   XXX        302   GET /Nav/
0x0354f26c      110 Sec        no      1366 Sec     XXX        200   GET /Nav/ResTry.aspx te
0x0355a45c      110 Sec       yes                   XXX        200   POST /Service/ResInhId_68022569!
0x035d8454      110 Sec       yes                   XXX        302   POST /Service/ResIntf.ashx act
0x035e1268      110 Sec        no      1213 Sec     XXX        200   GET /Nav/ResTry.aspx te
0x12e77088      110 Sec        no         6 Sec     XXX        200   GET /Nav/Activities.mvc/Index/2/7 
0x12e85b10      110 Sec        no         5 Sec     215        200   GET /service/Ressaveresult.aspx even
0x12e89cb8      110 Sec        no         5 Sec     XXX        200   GET /Nav/Activities.mvc/Index/2/5 topicid=1
0x12ed5038      110 Sec        no         4 Sec     XXX        200   GET /Nav/Ressave.aspx e
0x12ed9dc0      110 Sec       yes                   XXX        302   GET /Nav/DoItem.aspx ItemId=71937319
```

There's over 70 threads here but I trimmed the output.

Why do most of the ThreadId's not show up and appear as XXX?  If I use

```
 !threads
```

I see almost every ID but given that's missing the page names it's a bear to find out what they are doing.  The threads aren't marked completed and **I don't believe they're truly dead even though that's what the XXX allegedly means**.  When I looked at the currently executing requests in IIS many of these pages showed up.

If I run

```
 !threadpool
```

I do see dozens of threads running even though I only see a handful of ThreadId's without XXX which enforces the point that they're not dead but somehow WinDbg or psscor4 is not loading the ThreadId properly.

Another question is why these weren't sent a Thread.Abort by IIS and ran past their specified timeout.  Is it possible the thread that acts as the grim reaper was also delayed by the high CPU issue on the machine?  Can we verify this in windbg and identify this special thread somehow?

Comment: I would expect to see a number of XXX threads at any time due to how the thread pool works. This means that the OS thread is terminated, but the associated managed thread object is still available. You state that !aspxpages lists numerous threads. How does that correlate with the output of !threads?

Comment: !threads shows dozens of threadIDs so the XXX on psscor4 for almost all of them doesn't feel right.  Some sort of bug in psscor4 or odd condition?  Is there any way to manually cross-check what psscor4 is doing in !ASPXPages to debug further?

Answer (score 0):

ThreadId is usually XXXX for completed requests. They are still in memory because they have not been garbage collected yet. However it is strange, that you have XXXX also for requests where Completed=no. Try runing ~*e !clrstack to get stacks for all managed threads. In such a way. you will exactly see what is going on at the moment of dump.